# Canvas' .fillText function appears to stop working after first time called

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm just getting into drawing on the canvas (Canvas Noob). To practice, I'm just trying to create some transparent circle objects with text in the middle. The function that creates the text is called `writeName`. The first time I create a new instance of the object, it writes the word that I pass it. **The problem is** it does not write the text on the 2nd and 3rd instances of the object.

While trying to find any errors, I inserted a `console.log` in `writeName` which tells me that the function is getting called each time and the parameter is indeed passed to the function correctly, so I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I strongly suspect it has something to do with the way the `fillText`function works. What am I doing wrong? Why won't this work?

Here is the complete code for the page:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>

<script>

    // Global Variables.
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.textBaseline="middle";
    ctx.font = "20px Arial";

    // Function to generate the page icons.
    function pageObj(pgType, plot, lText) {
        writeName(plot[0], plot[1], lText);
        drwCirc(plot[0], plot[1]);
    }

    // Draws a circle for directories.
    function drwCirc(x, y){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, 60, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0)"; // Transparent fill.
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.lineWidth = 6;
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    // Writes the name of the file or directory in the circle.
    function writeName(x, y, text){
        console.log("X = " + x + "\n" + "Y = " + y + "\n" + "Text = " + text);
        ctx.fillText(text,x,y);
    }

    // The actual objects generated go here.
    var pageDemo = pageObj('dir', [500, 500], "index");
    var pageDemo1 = pageObj('dir', [250, 250], "page");
    var pageDemo2 = pageObj('dir', [0, 0], "tacos");


    //    ctx.beginPath();
    //    ctx.moveTo(centerX, centerY);
    //    ctx.lineTo(450, 50);
    //    ctx.stroke();
</script>
```

Comment: You need to set the fillStyle for the text. Currently you use the default ("black") then you set the `fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0)"` so next time you call fillText you will see nothing. BTW that will also include the arc. Having alpha as 0 will not render anything. To render transparent pixels you will need to use `ctx.clip` and `ctx.clearRect` or create masks and use `ctx.globalCompositeOperation` or manipulate the pixels directly with `ctx.getImageData` and `ctx.setImageData`

Comment: Thanks! That totally worked. You should put this as the answer so I can select it instead of just a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blindman67 gave me the answer. He put it in a comment but not as an answer to this question. I'm putting the answer here for anyone else who might be having the same or similar problem:

You need to set the fillStyle for the text. Currently you use the default ("black") then you set the fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0)" so next time you call fillText you will see nothing. BTW that will also include the arc. Having alpha as 0 will not render anything. To render transparent pixels you will need to use ctx.clip and ctx.clearRect or create masks and use ctx.globalCompositeOperation or manipulate the pixels directly with ctx.getImageData and ctx.setImageData